# Does using Standby Masters with ZooKeeper with hadoop prevent single point of failure

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper

In hadoop namenodes are a single point of failure. If you use a spark along side hadoop does Zookeeper take care of the single point of failure hadoop would normally have on its own? Or does it still rely on the namenode for the hdfs input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to elaborate:

> In hadoop namenodes are a single point of failure.

Well, if you have 2 NameNode's setup in active-standby mode using ZKFC(ZooKeeper Failover Controller) for auto failover in that case NameNode's are not a single point of failure.

> If you use spark along side hadoop does Zookeeper take care of the single point of failure hadoop would normally have on its own?

There are multiple ways how you could run/use spark along side hadoop.

- Use YARN to run Spark on containers
- Use Spark's standalone mode (which uses its own Spark master and workers), in this more you could use Zookeeper to make Spark master highly available, which is responsible for making scheduling decisions.

> Or does it still rely on the namenode for the hdfs input

Yes, Spark still has to reply on NameNode for reading the data from HDFS. Every HDFS Read/Write requests have to go through NameNode, which has the metadata information required to serve the actual data.